# How to avoid listing out function arguments but still subset too?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a function `myFun(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)` which contains a vectorised expression of its parameters within it.

I'd like to add a new column: `data$result <- with(data, myFun(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H))` where `A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H` are column names of `data`. I'm using `data.table` but `data.frame` answers are appreciated too.

So far the parameter list (column names) can be tedious to type out, and I'd like to improve readability. Is there a better way?

```
> myFun <- function(a,b,c) a+b+c
> dt <- data.table(a=1:5,b=1:5,c=1:5)
> with(dt,myFun(a,b,c))
[1]  3  6  9 12 15
```

The ultimate thing I would like to do is:

```
 dt[isFlag, newCol:=myFun(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H)]
```

However:

```
> dt[a==1,do.call(myFun,dt)]
[1]  3  6  9 12 15
```

Notice that the `j` expression seems to ignore the subset. The result should be just `3`.

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft gave you the answer - `dt[isFlag, newCol := do.call(myFun, dt)]`

Comment: oh, right, well, just filter inside the `do.call` as well

Comment: @eddi then that looks even uglier I would say

Comment: okay :) how about `dt[isFlag, newCol := do.call(myFun, .SD)]`

Comment: @eddi now that is what I would like to see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignoring the subset aspect for now: `df$result <- do.call("myFun", df)`. But that copies the whole `df` whereas `data.table` allows you to add the column by reference: `df[,result:=myFun(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H)]`.

To include the comment from @Eddi (and I'm not sure how to combine these operations in `data.frame` so easily) :

```
dt[isFlag, newCol := do.call(myFun, .SD)]
```

Note that `.SD` can be used even when you aren't grouping, just subsetting.

Or if your function is literally just adding its arguments together :

```
dt[isFlag, newCol := do.call(sum, .SD)]
```

This automatically places `NA` into `newCol` where `isFlag` is `FALSE`.

Comment: i am using `data.table`, but `df[,result:=myFun(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H)]` still has long parameter list

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
df$result <- do.call(myFun, df)
```